# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n} (z-1)^{2n}$ converges when

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n} (z-1)^{2n}$ converges when,

$1.|z|\le 3$

$2. |z|<\sqrt{3}$

$3.|z-1|<\sqrt{3}$

$4.|z-1|\le \sqrt{3}$

The radius of convergence can be found by applying the root test to the terms of the series. The root test uses the number $$C=\lim\sup|3^{-n}(z-1)^{2n}|^{1\over n}$$ for convergence $C<1$ and I get $|z-1|<\sqrt{3}$, Is it okay?

Comment: You are doing fine. It is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the root test.

Set $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left(3^{-n} (z -1)^{2n}\right)^{1/n} < 1.$$
Cancelling exponents leaves
$$|z - 1|^2/3 < 1$$
or $$|z - 1| < \sqrt{3}.$$
Note that this fails to converge at both endpoints.  It is, in fact, a geometric series.  You are lookin' good.